# UrlHelper.Link() returns null

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I know that there are a number of questions here that have this title, but, having been through them, I do not believe any of the posted solutions help.

I have the following code in a Web Api v2.1 Controller...

```
    [VersionedRoute("{id:int}", 1, Name="GetEvent")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var helper = new UrlHelper(Request);
            var link = helper.Link("GetEvent", new { id = id });
            var result = ApiBL.V1Get(id);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApiHttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

Putting a breakpoint on the line after the  line on which `link` is assigned, I can see that it is null. I can also see that Request has what I'd expect to see...

```
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:8087/atlas/api/events/50', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Basic blahblahblah
  Host: localhost:8087
  Content-Length: 31
  Content-Type: application/json
}}
```

And that `helper` is non-null.

Below is the definition of the `VersionedRouteAttribute` class

```
public class VersionedRouteAttribute : RouteFactoryAttribute
{
    public VersionedRouteAttribute(string template, int allowedVersion)
        : base(template)
    {
        AllowedVersion = allowedVersion;
    }

    public int AllowedVersion { get; private set; }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Constraints
    {
        get
        {
            var constraints = new HttpRouteValueDictionary();
            constraints.Add("version", new VersionConstraint(AllowedVersion));
            return constraints;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe, from everything I've read, that this should work. I simply can't figure out what's wrong. I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not convinced that the value of the named parameter `Name` is getting through to the base `RouteAttribute`

Comment: I've added details of the definition of the `versionedRouteAttribute` class to the original question, in case that _does_ turn out to be relevant.

Comment: Pants! It is somehow connected to the `VersionedRouteAttribute` class. If I replace it with a standard `RouteAttribute` it works. I've tried modiifying the `VersionedRouteAttribute` calls to take Name as a parameter and explicitly set on the base class and whilst I can see that it's being set, it's not making any difference!! :-(

Comment: Just to be clear, with the code as it is shown above, if I put a breakpoint on the getter of `VersionedRouteAttribute.Constraints` I can see that `Name` is properly set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are using the `RoutingConstraintsSample` from [**here**](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/RoutingConstraintsSample/ReadMe.txt) which demonstrates versioning with attribute routing...if yes, then the `VersionConstraint` in that sample has a bug...you can modify the `Match` method of that to like below:

```
public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    if (routeDirection == HttpRouteDirection.UriResolution)
    {
        int version = GetVersionHeader(request) ?? DefaultVersion;

        return (version == AllowedVersion);
    }

    return true; 
}
```

Also why are you instantiating `UrlHelper` yourself as its already provided to you by the `Url` property that is available on the controller.

Comment: @Kiran.You are correct that my `VersionedRouteAttribute` is based on the sample you referenced, and whilst my `VersionConstraint` is quite different (I've been asked to allow the API version to be described using any one of 4 different methods), I'd managed to reproduce the same bug in the `Match` method!

Comment: BTW, @Kiran, in my actual code, the UrlHelper is instansiated 'cos the code that generated the links is *not* in the Controller, but in a static Factory class; I had moved the code around a bit for the purposes of demonstrating the problem.